# How to login with Microsoft Account on Skype while logged in as a non administrator user

Tags: windows-xp, login, skype

I'm experiencing problems trying to login in Skype using my Microsoft Account. Whenever I click the Windows Account login option, Skype freezes.

I noticed this only happens when I'm logged in Windows with a non privileged user.

Plus, the only way to "unfreeze" is to quit Skype and clear cache stuff on Internet Explorer Options.

Does anyone is experiencing the same problems? Any idea how to solve this?

Some useful information:
- Windows Xp SP3 with all current updates
- Skype 6.9 newest version (out 2013)

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Skype on Windows XP because the problem does not exists on Windows 7.  I would report the bug to Microsoft through the normal channels.

Comment: I would have to agree.